# How to translate only the interface back to English?

Tags: i18n-l10n

My site default language is Hebrew (RTL), the problem is that it's all the site, and I want my sites admin-interface to be in English (American). how could I re-translate it to English?

Answer (score 4):

There is a module for that: [Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language).

> This module lets the administrator see all administration pages in his/her preferred language.
>
> You can use this to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).
>
> You can use the standard Languages page to choose the language of the admin pages.

Comment: well, i really want to do it without a module (i already have some modules in the site, and because i also love to update, i prefer to use a minimal number of modules). you wrote: "You can use the standard Languages page to choose the language of the admin pages." really? i didn't see such a page or such an option. the only option i have is to check if a particular language is the default one, or if it's active.